# Select consecutive integers from array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to select consecutive integers from an array, for example:

Input: (doesn't have to be sorted)

```
array = [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]
```

Expected output:

```
#=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
```

This is my code so far:

```
array = [1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 10, 8, 12, 13, 17]
newarray = []
z = 0
array.sort.each_cons(2) do |x, y|
  if y == x + 1
    if z == 0
      newarray.insert(0, x, y)
    else
      newarray.push(y)
    end
  end
  z = z + 1
end

newarray #=> [7, 8, 9, 10, 13]
```

As you can see, `6` and `12` are missing.

What's wrong with my code and - besides the bug - is there a better way to write it?

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to code review which may be a better place to ask: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  You should also give more example input and output and explain what your code is *supposed* to do. E.g. Is the correct output for `[1,2,3,6,5]` supposed to be `[1,2,3,6]` (i.e. it will miss out the value 5)?

Comment: Corrected the question @NeilSlater

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: You have not explained what you are trying to do. Instead, you have left it to the reader to figure that out from your code. That's probably why you've received downvotes. You need to edit your question to first explain what you want to do. Give examples that include expected/desired output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs  on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com requires valid code. Since the OP's code contains bugs (values are missing), it is off-topic over there. I'm therefore voting to reopen the question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code compares adjacent elements `x` and `y`, but pushes `x` and `y` only if they are the first elements in the array (`if z == 0; newarray.insert(0, x, y)`). Otherwise, only `y` is pushed, so the first element of each group of consecutive integers is missing.

This table illustrates what's going on:

```
  x   y   y == x+1
--------------------
  1   3   false
  3   6   false
  6   7   true      #=> push(7)
  7   8   true      #=> push(8)
  8   9   true      #=> push(9)
  9  10   true      #=> push(10)
 10  12   false
 12  13   true      #=> push(13)
 13  17   false
```

You could fix your code by using `z` as an indicator for the beginning of a group:

```
z = true
array.sort.each_cons(2) do |x, y|
  if y == x + 1
    if z
      newarray.push(x, y)
      z = false
    else
      newarray.push(y)
    end
  else
    z = true
  end
end
```

A better way is to use [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) that was introduced in Ruby 2.3:

```
array = [1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 10, 8, 12, 13, 17]

array
  .sort                              #=> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17]
  .chunk_while { |x, y| y == x + 1 } #=> [[1], [3], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13], [17]]
  .select { |a| a.size > 1 }         #=> [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13]]
  .flatten                           #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
```

Did you notice that the documentation contains a similar example?

> For example, one-by-one increasing subsequence can be chunked as follows:
>
> ```
> a = [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]
> b = a.chunk_while {|i, j| i+1 == j }
> p b.to_a #=> [[1, 2], [4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [19, 20, 21]]
> ```