# Remove groups of consecutive numbers from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 23, 34, 35, 36, 45, 50, 51, ...]
```

I'm trying to remove each group of consecutive numbers so I end up with:

```
[6, 23, 45, ...]
```

I am looking for anomalies in serial ids.  Does anyone have suggestions?

My initial attempt only checks for the id before each element:

```
non_consecutive_ids = []
ids.each_with_index do |x, i|
  unless x == ids[i-1] + 1
    non_consecutive_ids << x
  end
end
```

The thing I think I was missing was to also check to see if the next element in the array is 1 more than the current.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select consecutive integers from array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785667/select-consecutive-integers-from-array-in-ruby)

Comment: would it not be `3, 6, 10, 23, 36, 45, 51?`

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the work you have done so far in trying to solve this problem on your own? Why don't any of the [many similar answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+array+consecutive) on stackoverflow answer the question for you?

Comment: @anothermh The answer to the possible duplicate you referenced has what I need, but the question is the opposite of what I was trying to do. It's also flagged as not a very good question. I searched, but most of the questions I found were not doing exactly what I was looking for. Will update my question with the code I first attempted with.

Comment: @JoshBrody That could be a resulting array, but not what I'm looking for. I really do want the result to exclude each entire group of consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select` and check the surrounding values:

```
array.select.with_index{ |x, index| (array[index-1] != x-1) && (array[index+1] != x+1)}
```

Comment: `array = [1,3,0]; arr.select.with_index{ |x, index| (array[index-1] != x-1) && (array[index+1] != x+1)} #=> [0]`. The problem is when `index #=> 0`, `array[index-1] #=> 0`.

Answer (score 8):

Other option:

```
array.chunk_while { |i, j| i + 1 == j }.select { |e| e.size == 1 }.flatten
#=> [6, 23, 45]
```

The good of [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) is that it takes two params. The core doc has just an example of a one-by-one increasing subsequence.

Comment: Nice one. Invariably, one can flip a coin to decide whether to use `Enumerable#chunk_while` or [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (`a.slice_when { |a,b| b != a + 1 }...`).